# How to use options(error=recover) in an R program with many layers of try()?

Tags: r, debugging, try-catch

I'm trying to debug a large complex R codebase with multiple layers of error trapping using `try()stop()` and `withCallingHandlers()`. The problem I'm facing is that `options(error=recover)` and RStudio's `Rerun with debug` fail to open the debugger at the deepest error location (where I want to debug) and instead open at the latest `try()stop()` handler (which has lost the important information).

My current work-around is to temporarily remove the `try()` error trapping and rerun, which is quite clumsy. I really don't want to temporarily redefine `try <- function(x)x`.

Is there a way to run `options(error=recover)` and recover at the first error?